# How to detect small circles within dark regions in the X-ray image?

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, contour

I have the following X-ray image copied from the [link](https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=eWxZHBuo&id=925D2DFBFDB12519A8341E1622371879C5962318&thid=OIP.eWxZHBuo0X5BffZXg2HwKQHaHa&mediaurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.circuitsassembly.com%2Fca%2Fimages%2Fstories%2FArticleImages%2F1803%2Ftest4.jpg&cdnurl=https%3A%2F%2Fth.bing.com%2Fth%2Fid%2FR.796c591c1ba8d17e417df6578361f029%3Frik%3DGCOWxXkYNyIWHg%26pid%3DImgRaw&exph=700&expw=700&q=Xray%20void%20in%20bunps&simid=607986031433945652&FORM=IRPRST&ck=340140E5616654C2ADD84F9C63049894&selectedIndex=31&ajaxhist=0&ajaxserp=0). [image]

I could successfully extract dark big regions  (circles) using Open CV (Python) contour detection and or circle detection. However, my interest is to extract small circles (Multiple light color circles ) inside big dark regions.
My approach was first to extract the big dark regions into an array and then extract smaller circles within each big dark region. However, the second step is not successful since it radii differ significantly. What are the other avenues available for that ? I was able to increase the contrast by image multiplication. Also Canny edge detector was able to select big dark region edges.

Comment: You could try doing Canny edge detection to get all the circles. Then use HoughCircles to detect the size circles that you want.

Comment: the small ones can only be inside the big ones? maybe thresholdin or houghCircles will be easier if you crop the big ones first

Comment: I would recommend tomography, i.e. get a 3d volumetric view of the solder joints. apart from that, some deep learning would certainly solve problems of this level. or try a (Fast) Radial Symmetry Transform (RST/FRST). it's kinda like a hough transform but it also tells you the "sign". you're only looking for light circles not dark circles.

Comment: I would like to try RST/FRST. It's new to me. Yes, DL work is on my table in case classical techniques don't work

Comment: You can try OpenCV Houghcircle however it looks like there is some perspective that may affect the detection of circles (my humble experience, I found that Hough Circles works best if circles are perfect, and works less on Ellipsys shape).

Alternatively you can try to detect the small circles using OpenCV Blob Detector

Comment: Hough circle works fine with detecting the dark regions but not the smaller onces. It is too noisy. Decided to use machine learning to detect smaller circles within dark regions.